# Adjoint of a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V=M_n(\mathbb C)$ i.e the set of all $n\times n$ matrices over $\mathbb C$ Define an inner product $\langle A,B\rangle =trace(B^*A)$

Define $T:V\rightarrow V$ by $T(A)=MA$;

what is $T^*(A)$?

$B^*$ denotes adjoint of $B$

I have verified it to be an inner product but cant find the meaning of this question .Any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The adjoint is defined by
$\langle T^*(X),Y \rangle = \langle X, T(Y) \rangle$.

To see what this 'means', fix some $X$ and look at the map $Y \mapsto \langle X, T(Y) \rangle$. This
is a linear, scalar valued, continuous map hence the Reisz representation theorem
tells us that there is some $Z$ such that the map can be written as
$Z \mapsto \langle Z, Y \rangle$. Now define $T^*(X) = Z$. A bit more
work shows that the map $X \mapsto T^*(X)$ is linear and continuous.

Here you have
$\langle X, T(Y) \rangle = \operatorname{tr} ((MY)^* X)= \operatorname{tr} (Y^* M^* X) = \langle M^* X, Y \rangle$. Since this holds for all $Y$, we have
$T^*(X) = M^* X$.

Comment: can't this be done only using linear algebra;it's a problem on linear algebra

Comment: if $T:V\rightarrow T$ where is $T^*$ going from?

Comment: $T^*:V \to V$, this is the Hilbert space adjoint.